# How to send email through VBA when scheduled in Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, task, scheduler

I have code which will send email when done through a button click.

I have scheduled the same code to run periodically through Task Scheduler. The mail gets in draft stage.

Issue 1: if I use `.Send`, there is a security pop up with allow or deny options

Issue 2: to avoid the above pop up, I used `.Display`,  wait for the application and sendkeys --> this is working when run through button click but when run through scheduler the email stays in draft stage.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997658/excel-vba-script-does-not-send-outlook-items-when-in-task-scheduler-and-run-whe alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514690/outlook-task-scheduler-to-run-access-subs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257985/outlook-vba-run-a-code-every-half-an-hour

Answer (score 0):

> Issue 1 : if I use .send in mail, it ask for a security pop up with allow or deny option

This is a standard security prompt in Outlook. "Security" in this context refers to the so-called "object model guard" that triggers security prompts and blocks access to certain features in an effort to prevent malicious programs from harvesting email addresses from Outlook data and using Outlook to propagate viruses and spam. These prompts cannot simply be turned off, except in Outlook 2007 with an anti-virus application running. [This page](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=52) discusses strategies for avoiding security prompts.

> Issue 2 : to avoid the above pop up, I have used .display, wait for the application and sendkeys -->

All current versions of Microsoft Office were designed, tested, and configured to run as end-user products on a client workstation. They assume an interactive desktop and user profile. They do not provide the level of reentrancy or security that is necessary to meet the needs of server-side components that are designed to run unattended.

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0) article.

As a possible workaround, you may use a low-level API which doesn't trigger security prompts - Extended MAPI. Or just any wrappers around this API such as Redemption. It allows bridging both issues.